# iOS 9 Adaptable font sizes?

Tags: swift, ios9

I'm trying to get my font sizes to scale with the change of system wide (via iOS Settings), but I am only able to get this functionality if I set `Text Style` to Body, etc in the `Interface Builder`.

I guess a way to do it could be to get the system font then factor that up a bit to get a new font-size to use:

```
    let bodyFont = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleBody)
    label.font = UIFont(descriptor: bodyFont.fontDescriptor(), size: bodyFont.pointSize * 1.2)
```

But is there a better way, because this feels wrong.

And is there a way to get notified when system font size change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to listen to this notification: `UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification`

If you wanted to further increase those sizes, then you can do what you have suggested. Just be careful if the user chooses the really large font sizes in accessibility settings, as your fonts would be even bigger then.

Comment: So I need to listen for this on each of my labels? Would that drain a lot of batter or will be fine?

Comment: I would suggest listening to this in your active ViewController and then have a method that is called that updates all your labels font sizes. It will be fine for the battery, it will only be called if the user changes their font size. This is a good example: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/supporting-dynamic-type.html

Comment: That sounds like a very bad idea for this app I'm working on - I have a lot of different text. I have a very long tableview with many different views that could pop in and out and need to adapt. It would tightly couple the components to the viewcontroller. This sounds very messy to maintain.

Comment: Hi, if its a tableView you are showing, you could create a method in your cell that sets the font of the labels, then in your viewcontroller when you get the notification you can loop over the tableView.visibleCells() and call that method to update the font.

Comment: I'm gonna call this an answer, but it's not really a good approach to loop through things to change, it sounds very spaghetti code.